# How to export some rows in some tables in mysql database with condition by php function?

Tags: php, mysql

I writing an API to export data from database. I will export data of 5 tables: `table_1, table_2, table_3, table_4, table_5` with the same condition `where="clock>='.$from.' and clock <= '.$to.'"`

Exam: `$from = 1564009035 and $to = 1564009215`

How to write the SQL query and execute in PHP function to do that?

Please help me,
Thank you so much,
BienHV

Answer (score 0):

if you want to export 5 tables in different result, you can do sql like this to every table `SELECT * FROM table_1` until your fifth table, then use `json_decode()` to your sql result if you want to export the data to an json file and use it as API

Comment: Thank for your help, But I want to save the export file with SQL format. Example export_data.sql.zip as export from phpmyadmin. How to do that?

Comment: you want to export the data result from your sql query to be an SQL format?

Comment: Hi friends, I am using this shell script to export. It work fine. However, I want to export for REPLACE content when import. How to do that? This is my export secript:  mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot -pFsoft@12345 --default-character-set=utf8 databasename table_1 --where "clock>=1564009035", table_2 --where "clock>=1564009035", table_3 --where "clock>=1564009035", table_4 --where "clock>=1564009035" --single-transaction --no-create-info > /var/www/html/zabbix/upload/file.sql

Comment: I am sorry, i am not familiar with shell script, but I suggest you to save your new replace data inside a table and export it

Comment: since you say that you want to export an REPLACE content, I suggest you to update the data inside your table

Comment: Thank for your idea! Could you help me. How to export with update command line?

Comment: use this, `UPDATE 'your_table' SET 'your_column'=[your_value] WHERE your_clock = another_clock`